# Require classes from another dll as an input to API?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, interface, projects-and-solutions

I have 3 C# projects: A, B, and C. B references C and A references B (A -> B -> C). B is an API for A and C does some lower level work for B.

B exposes some public methods to A that currently require a class from C as an input. Is there a way for A to be able to create instances of the required class without referencing C directly?

Is it bad for B to require a class from C in its API? Would it be better to create a class in B that mirrors the class from C so that B only exposes an API that is entirely dependent on itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Is there a way for A to be able to create instances of the required class without referencing C directly?"

Not if you want A to know that's what it's doing, no. You can, of course, have A call B to create an instance of some interface they both know and which is implemented by a class in C.

> "Is it bad for B to require a class from C in its API?"

Bad in what way? There is certainly precedent for this in a variety of libraries, including .NET itself. It doesn't seem inherently bad to me, and it can be the best way to solve what would otherwise involve a circular reference (not that that's at issue in your scenario, but it does come up, and this is a way to solve it).

> "Would it be better to create a class in B that mirrors the class from C so that B only exposes an API that is entirely dependent on itself?"

There are sometimes good reasons to create such proxy objects, but to do it for the sole purpose of hiding a type in one DLL from another DLL? No, I don't see how that's better. If you want to accomplish something *like* that, the right way is to declare an interface, known by A and B, and implemented by a class in C.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You've given me some confidence and for now I will just reference C in A... it still feels a little bit wrong though because A doesn't really care about C (A only wants to use B). I will ponder over your other advice as well. Thanks again!